# Weird LI white space issue in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css

I have a strange issue which has been bugging me all day.
On the following page: http://www.abbey-garage.co.uk/manufacturer.php?id_manufacturer=4

Basically, if I view this page in Firefox, each list item (vehicle listing) has a small amount of spacing between them (around 10 pixels)... however in Internet Explorer this is dramatically increased to around 100px!!

Could anyone shed any light as to what might be causing this?

Many Thanks! :)

Comment: You've got a bunch of tags that aren't closed. Validate your HTML: http://goo.gl/8sQ1t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres two problems here. First is the 100% width here at line 1548 in global.css:

```
ul#product_list li div.center_block {
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%
}
```

Remove the width and you should be fine.

Second problem is the way the price is forced under the picture at line 1552 of global.css

```
ul#product_list li div.right_block {
    margin-right: 1em;
    width: 11em;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 155px;
}
```

There are better ways to do this... Change the above to the next and it should work better...

```
ul#product_list li div.right_block {
    margin-right: 1em;
    width: 11em;
    text-align: left;
    clear: left;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}
```

Though no garantuees here, the html is a mess and hard to debug especially in IE.

Comment: It actually turned out to be a programming issue... one of the functions within the PHP template engine of prestashop was truncating some of the product description before stripping it of HTML.. this was basically causing unclosed tags etc within the HTML so after some playing I managed to get this solved!